Reimbursement of assurance chomage after contract termination and permanent departure from France- titre de sejour holder
I am a titre de sejour holder (passeport talent). My 2 yrs contract finishes next month (May2024) and residence permit experies in July 2024. I am aware that I am entitled to uemployement money if I had decided to stay in France without a valid job because of the monthly tax i have paid with my salary called the assurance chomage.
I am returning back to my country and I was hoping if there is a way to reimburse this money, as I will not be taking the benefit of this.
Does anyone know how and if this is possible. Your help is greatly appreciated.

No, this is not possible.
Instead, it is sometimes possible:

To get some benefits while looking for a job in another EU or EEA country
To get deferred benefits if you decide to come back to France

